# Copy value of cell from multiple workbooks to a master file

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

In work I want to consolidate data from some excel workbooks into single master file. I can't install any other programs or tool due to UAC and stuff, so I have to use vba. Edit: Im also stuck with Excel 2010 with doesn't have consolidate tool built in.

I have some code done but I'm stuck. I want to copy specified range form many workbooks(A1:A35) into columns of master file. Each columns of master is each file. Problem with my code is that it doesn't move to next column for next file.

```vb
Sub Get_Columns()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFil As String
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Dim twb As Workbook

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xlsx")

    Do While sFil <> "" And sFil <> twb.Name
        Set owb = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFil)
        twb.Sheets("Podsumowanie").Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1) = owb.Sheets("Wyniki").Range("A1:A35").Value
        owb.Close False 'Close no save
        sFil = Dir

    Loop

        With Application
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried Excel's built-in consolidation?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Edited my post. Excel 2010 don't have that option.

Comment: I have used Consolidation since Excel 5, so I'm quite sure it is available in 2010 as well. Are you allowed to activate the default add-ins?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the single copy line with these three.

You need to refer to `Columns.count`, not `rows.count` as you want to go the last column and then work backwards. (Cells is row, column).

```
With owb.Sheets("Wyniki").Range("A1:A35")
    twb.Sheets("Podsumowanie").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```